# Polar coordinates: $ \iint_D (\sqrt{a^2 - x^2 -y^2} - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I need to calculate the following integral
$$\iint_D \left(\sqrt{a^2 - x^2 -y^2} - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y$$

where $D$ is the disk $x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2$

Using the transformation to polar coordinates $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$, we have the new integration region
$$ 0 < r < a$$
$$ 0 < \theta < 2 \pi$$

and the integral will be

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a \left(\sqrt{a^2 - r^2} - r\right)r \:\mathrm{d}r\:\mathrm{d}\theta$$

But I am getting $0$ as answer, which is not the given answer.

What am I doing wrong? Or maybe is the answer wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to believe why $0$ is incorrect? I also get 0 for the inner integral.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. I meant that this is not the book answer, but it can be right, of course. I thought that I make something wrong

Comment: Textbooks make mistakes all the time. Your work looks correct to me.

Comment: What is the book's answer?

Comment: Presumably, $-a\le r\le a$ and $0\le\theta\le\pi$?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey, how can be $-a\le r\le a$? $r\ge 0$ by definition, right?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Just my wild guess. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using polar co-ordinates as you have, we have:

$$\iint_{D}\left(\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}}-\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)\:\mathrm{d}A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{a}r\left(\sqrt{a^{2}-r^{2}}-r\right)\:\mathrm{d}r\:\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Expanding the integrand we have:

$$2\pi\int_{0}^{a}(r\sqrt{a^{2}-r^{2}}-r^{2})\:\mathrm{d}r=2\pi\left[-\frac{1}{3}(a^{2}-r^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{r^{3}}{3}\right]_{0}^{a}$$

Expanding this out we get:

$$2\pi\left(-\frac{a^{3}}{3}+\frac{a^{3}}{3}\right)=2\pi\left(0\right)=0$$

Which is what you have calculated.

Comment: You need not also calculate the inner integrand explicitly. Just note that if you make the substitution $u=\sqrt{a^2-r^2}$, and if your original integrand is $I$, then you'll get, $I=-I$.